# Bind a key to the search of a specific word in Emacs

Tags: key-bindings, search

I would like to bind `Ctrl + F` aka `C-f` to find the first occurrence of the word "fun". Basically, I was this key to do the same thing as pressing `C-s` and typing `"fun"<Enter>`. Here's what I tried:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") (lambda () (interactive) (isearch-forward "fun")))
```

But this simply runs the `isearch-forward` command without the "fun" argument.

Comment: Have a look at the docstring for `isearch-forward` to understand why it's not interpreting your argument like you expect.  Try `search-forward` instead.

Comment: Please consider accepting your own answer. This is still showing up as an unanswered question. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding Dan's comment, the solution is to use `search-forward` instead of `isearch-forward`:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") (lambda () (interactive) (search-forward "fun")))
```